# Redis as a replacement for Modbus/TCP

Tags: redis, iot, modbus, modbus-tcp

I'm currently using Redis in an IoT application to receive a stream of data from an acquisition board; all other communications between the PC and the board is based on Modbus/TPC protocol.

A colleague of mine has recently advanced the proposal to completely remove Modbus, and use Redis for all communications instead.
Supposedly this would require a mixture of variables exchange and PUB/SUB signals.

While the idea is attractive, I was just wondering if someone has already done some research in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Modbus is a widely used protocol to communicate between industrial devices on one side and computers / gateways on the other side. The device is the server, the computer is the client. Sensor data is polled, changes are pushed.

Redis provides a protocol RESP https://redis.io/topics/protocol between REDIS clients and the Redis server. The devices would then be clients, and the computer the server.

Replacing modbus with RESP would thus invert the client/server relationship.
While there are advantages (better typed data transfer) its uncommon the select a RESP in that area. MQTT or so would be more common.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan Vaillant for sharing your opinions.

Following your picture:
1) "changes are pushed": with Redis, the device could update variables as needed after any change,
2) "data is polled": with Redis, the application could read the variables periodically to collect changed.
And we might also take advantage of PUB/SUB to add notifications.
Having the device act as a client rather than a server would also be beneficial for us.

So, nothing seems to be lost by dropping Modbus.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the software stack as simple as possible, so I don't mind adding more components (like RabbitMQ, for example) but only if really needed; since Redis is already required for other needs, let me ask: which possible advantages could be offered by MQTT, in your opinion ?

Comment: I both components (PC and board) are owned by you and always sold together, and they are co-located (i.e. the board is directly attached to PC), the REDIS should IMHO could work. (I am not a REDIS expert).
If one of this is not the case, I would by default use not use REDIS.

Comment: Thank you. What you describe is actually our real case: the board is directly connected to the PC running Redis server.
I already had occasion to use this configuration to exchange real-time data with good results, even with limited resources (for example using Raspberry Pi to run the Redis server) but mainly in a LAN.
For completeness, let me say that occasionally we collected signals from a remote board (mainly as a convenience during the board development phase) with no problems.

Comment: In my opinion the benefits of this solutions are:
(1) given that the redis-server is already available and consolidated, you are really developing two clients, and (2) redis comes with useful tools for monitoring the communication (redis-cli monitor) and measuring (regis-benchmark) data exchange performances.
Having said this, I'll be certainly check the MQTT option you suggested.